# Extract an alphanumeric string between two special characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to match strings in the lines of a file and write the matches minus the first one and the last one

```
import os, re

infile=open("~/infile", "r")
out=open("~/out", "w")
pattern=re.compile("=[A-Z0-9]*>")
for line in infile:
    out.write( pattern.search(line)[1:-1] + '\n' )
```

Problem is that it says that `Match` is not subscriptable, when I try to add `.group()` it says that `Nonegroup has no attritube group`, `groups()`   returns that `.write` needs a tuple etc

Any idea how to get `.search` to return a string ?

Comment: If you want a string why not use `re.findall`?

Comment: If it says that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`, that means the search was unsuccessful.

Comment: @PhilipTzou you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre :P just lazy.

Comment: Just a `re.findall` is not enough since OP needs to actually get rid of `=` and `>` in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to need only the part of strings between `=` and `>`. In this case, it is much easier to use a *capturing group* around the alphanumeric pattern and use it with `re.findall` that will never return `None`, but just an empty list upon no match, or a list of captured texts if found. Also, I doubt you need empty matches, so use `+` instead of `*`:

```
pattern=re.compile(r"=([A-Z0-9]+)>")
                      ^         ^
```

and then

```
"\n".join(pattern.findall(line))
```

Answer (score 14):

The `re.search` function returns a `Match` object.

If the match fails, the `re.search` function will return None. To extract the matching text, use the `Match.group` method.

```
>>> match = re.search("a.", "abc")
>>> if match is not None:
...     print(match.group(0))
'ab'
>>> print(re.search("a.", "a"))
None
```

---

That said, it's probably a better idea to use groups to find the required section of the match:

```
>>> match = re.search("=([A-Z0-9]*)>", "=abc>")  # Notice brackets
>>> match.group(0)
'=abc>'
>>> match.group(1)
'abc'
```

This regex can then be used with findall as @WiktorStribiżew suggests.

Comment: The OP is already doing that, and they're getting an error with it because there was no match.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary that the error that you think he's getting is the one.